# Search results show a different site

Tags: seo, wordpress.com-hosting

I've just started with `wordpress.com` (not *wordpress.org*), and have two questions about google search results.

1. If I search my blog name *saltandsitecore*, it shows right up on the first page.
   Now, I search for *Building A Sitecore Website With MVC*, which is a title in all my posts. None of the results show my posts. Not even on the 10th page or later....But there is the following result in page 3. [You can also try and see]

> Building A Sitecore Website With MVC — Blogs, Pictures, and more on 
>   hy.wordpress.com/tag/building-a-sitecore-website-with-mvc/

I was expecting the result to have my blog site address, but it is some other *hy.wordpress*. Why is it so? Is this by default. If the search engine was able to find "hy.wordpress", why is it not finding the original blog.

Can I do something to get my blog site name there?

2. In extension to the above question, none of the search results came up with my blog name. What can I do to get my blog in the first pages? Does it depend on the number of visits for the posts?

Other than upgrading for SEO, what other tips would you suggest to get the posts some nice ranking?

The blog I need help with is `saltandsitecore.wordpress.com`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so for **#1** I would suggest you get the [WordPress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plug-in onto your site and by default with no changes once installed it'll help optimize your site for the best [Website Ranking](http://www.seomark.co.uk/how-does-google-rank-websites/).

Furthermore this plug-in adds a box near the bottom of all pages, posts, and media objects which allow you to see how a Google search might look for your post and it allows you to modify that output to make changes to different elements in the box rather than the post's default meta data otherwise.

> [image] <sub>[image
>   source](http://www.londonacademyofit.co.uk/learning-blog/wordpress/using-yoast-seo-plugin-wordpress/)</sub>

**2. "What can I do to get my blog in the first pages."**

The [Website Rankings](http://www.seomark.co.uk/how-does-google-rank-websites/) of a site that links to your site is important. If an [Authoritative Site](https://seo-bestpractices.com/internet-marketing-2/what-is-an-authoritative-s) links to your site or a specific post on your site then your search engine ranking for that post would increase signifigantly.

When the [Authoritative Site](https://seo-bestpractices.com/internet-marketing-2/what-is-an-authoritative-s) links to other posts, those posts inherit some of the authority when sites like this link to other sites. It's as if the [Authoritative Site](https://seo-bestpractices.com/internet-marketing-2/what-is-an-authoritative-s) puts a stamp of approval on sites they link so these sites get the ranking boosts.

Having [Authoritative Sites](https://seo-bestpractices.com/internet-marketing-2/what-is-an-authoritative-s) link to your posts is a good method to boost a site ranking.

Comment: I'm using the online wordpress.com and not wordpress.org.., which means I can't install the plugins...right?

Comment: That may be correct at which point you'd have to do manually what SEO by Yoast does which sounds like a pain. I've only used WP on my own hosted servers so I'm not real sure about a hosted solution but the hosting company may be able to help steer you in the right direction if you're able to ask them. Here's a post I found that mentioned some of the things the SEO by Yoast plug-in does... https://teslathemes.com/blog/how-to-optimize-your-wordpress-site-without-any-seo-plugins/